# Why is Shrinkwrap making the tube flat?

Tags: modifiers

I have a basic sphere, and with Freehand Addon I have created an arc and bevel that with the circle. To the arc its been bevel like a tube shape.
[image]

**Tube shape** [image]

Adding *Shrinkwrap* modifier the tube shape became flat

**Tube flat** [image]

Why has the tube gone flat after adding shrinkwrap modifier?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a button *Apply Modifier on Splines' Points* that you have to enable.

With the function deactivated the curve will get beveled and the resulting surface will receive the shrinkwrap modification. With the function activated all of the curve's control points will be shrinkwrapped. The bevel will then be applied to the shrinkwrapped curve.

[image: apply on spline]