# How would I model Tsuka wrapping?

Tags: bezier-curves, shrinkwrap, solidify-modifier

I'm trying to model a Tsuka wrapping and what I tried was to use a shrinkwrap so that my bezier curves get around a mesh I made.

Problem is that when I'm using a shrinkwrap it flattens my custom bezier curves. The solution offered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77390/why-is-shrinkwrap-making-the-tube-flat) isn't working for me.

I tried to play with offsets and use a Solidify modifier but Solidify just destroys the particular shape I'm using.

I'm at the point where I don't know what to try since I tried to change the settings in all the possible ways I could think with or without solidify.
How could I do this?

Left is my bezier curves spiral and right is a Circle I converted into a curve to use it on my spiral as an object in the geometry settings.
[image: Image 01]

Here is what I get when I use the shrinkwrap modifier. As you can see my custom shape is all flattened.
[image: Image02]

Using a solidify modifier is not getting the result I want.
[image: ![Image03]

If by any chance there is a kind soul to find a solution on this issue: how could I twist a specific part of the spiral so that it rotates 360 degrees on itself? I tried changing the rotation axis of a point of the curve but it wasn't affecting it.

[image: Image04]

Comment: You could do it in two steps: shrinkwrap with an offset to place the curve and apply the shrinkwrap. Then bevel the curve.

Comment: Finally, I think cutting (knife tool), the base mesh should be more efficient in your case. The cut can have the shape you need. Once done (on a copy of the mesh), keep it alone then this is your curve.

Comment: Hi, 줄리앙Julien. While the shrinkwrap part has been specifically answered in a duplicate. I think the rest of your question is a very interesting and challenging one. If you could edit the question to ask more simply: 'How would I model Tsuka Wrapping?' I think it could be re-opened.

Comment: @Robin Betts : Thank you I just edited my post.

Comment: @lemon : I'm not sure to correctly understand the part using the knife. Would you mind showing a simple example?

Comment: @줄리앙Julien, I could if the question is reopened...

Comment: This _is_ tricky, I think. (It's 2 opposing stepped-spirals, with the  height-changes entirely in the twists.) The twists are through 360, not 180 degrees. I beginning to have some luck with the tool provided in the shipped _Tissue_ add-on: 'Lattice along Surface'. That means you can model a twisted-ribbon-pair-array in the flat, and then conform it to the handle without losing depth. the But that answer might take some time. @lemon's approach might prove to be more reasonable.

Comment: @lemon It's reopened if you are still willing to show :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Do you think that lemon's approach and using CTRL+T to change the angle of the curves before working on the mesh could be good? I just found out about the ctrl+t shortcut to work on twisting angles. I have to try this on my side.

Comment: I haven't forgotten all about you...

Comment: @줄리앙Julien   Progress:  https://imgur.com/a/2LXuiWF but I've run into a Blender bug which makes it very twitchy for someone not familiar with it. Sorry about the delay.

Comment: @RobinBetts thanks for the feedback. Your test is looking very good, did you get to fold them? I went the hard way by manually modeling the Ito with Solidify modifiers and make loops that I repeat with an Array modifier. I have some other minor issues but I'm quite happy with the result I got. I don't know if I can/should post what I did in  the answer to my post.

Comment: @줄리앙Julien I'm so sorry to be late with this. I've had time to do little things, but not bigger ones. In mine, virtually no twist in the geometry. All an illusion in the shader, manipulating the UV map. Sure go ahead and post an image of your progress on imgur, and put a link in a comment, or in your question, whichever you feel is best.

Comment: @줄리앙Julien  This is getting so late as an answer, the best I can do is chuck you a file :  https://blend-exchange.com/b/yo5XdqNs/  . It includes a GN group which maps any object modelled in the XY plane 1: to the unit square, 2: to the corresponding positions of the selected UV map on a target object. And then thickens along the normals. You may find that useful.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hey no worries thank you for sharing your test file! Here is a picture of what I have been working on. I'm pretty happy but my geometry feels terrible and I'm having issues when I apply a texture and depending on the faces it's not going in the same direction as other faces that are around. https://imgur.com/wzQva0l I will take a look at your file