# how do I reduce the offset of the curve modifier for the following scene?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices

[image]

I want to make it so that the stitches (stitch object) lines up perfectly with the below mesh and kinda sticks to it, (I tried the shrinkwrap modifier but it is giving me very weird results)

[image]

As you can see there is a bit of a gap between the two mesh surfaces and I have to manually use the proportional editing tool to make it stick to the shoe surface.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77390/why-is-shrinkwrap-making-the-tube-flat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not strictly an answer, here.. but it can be a bit of a pain aligning separate curves and modifying, for stitched seams. Maybe some variation of this GN group would be good enough.

- It takes as input a vertex-group marking seams on the base-mesh to be stitched, and a stitch object.
- It aligns stitch X to the tangent of the seam, and stitch Z to the normal of the underlying surface.
- It doesn't deform stitches to the curve, but for small stitches, that should be OK
- The output is the stitched mesh,and an attribute on mesh-points: 'Distance from Stitches', which a mesh material might use for bump-mapping a groove or mound around the seam.

[image]

This sort of result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi, how to do you rotate the stitch object such that it follows the curve direction and not normal to the curve points

Comment: In the sample file, the stitch-object (X) _is_ following the curve direction.. to use this tool, you would just mark an edge-loop on the entire shoe to be stitched and save it as a vertex group.. no need for a separate curve. I'll get to demonstrating on your file, for you, later today.

Comment: I tried to mark the vertex group, but since I have solidify modifier on, the nodes modifier is showing irratic results, only by duplicating the edges and making it a curve is helping at this point

Comment: Hi, @AtharvaDeodhar   [Here's an example](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BZnZVVaK/). You would have to mark the vertex group on the base mesh, or a copy of it, with the modifiers applied. That may be a disadvantage for your workflow. The advantages are: you can quickly assign multiple seams, and adjust the stitches themselves very easily. I've reoriented your stitch object in Edit Mode, to comply. I've added a switch to the group so it can output only stitches.

Answer (score 3):

i am not totally sure, but don't you want just to apply the rotation of your curve to get this?

[image]

Comment: It is the relative rotation that's out of whack. But when that's fixed there are other things to fix, too.

Answer (score 3):

The offset depends on the position of the object relative to the curve:

[image]

One easy way to match positions would be to  have the origin of the curve object at one end of some spline  and the origin of the object at one end as well and then just place the object at the position of the origin of the curve:

[image]