# My object doesn't curve inwards along the path

Tags: modeling, modifiers, origin

I am trying to follow 'Polygon Runways' Factory Animation Tutorial, but I am stuck at 03:24, notice how the plane curves along the path, when I do it, this is how it behaves, in the tutorial video, it curves inside the object, how do I fix it?

Link to the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhzcCsR_EO0&t=44s&pp=ygUZYmxlbmRlciBmYWN0b3J5IGFuaW1hdGlvbg%3D%3D

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I reduce the offset of the curve modifier for the following scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294584/how-do-i-reduce-the-offset-of-the-curve-modifier-for-the-following-scene)

Answer (score 3):

The *Curve* modifier is sensitive to the locations and orientations of the origins of the curve and the modified object. In the tutorial, they seem to be as shown below:

[image]

(In Object Mode: Header > 'Options', you can choose to manipulate the origins of your objects, rather than the objects themselves, including, for example, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> snapping to 3D cursor)

Once those are set, the X array should work as intended, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> should animate:

[image]